# adding unique values to existing table in mySql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Good Day

I created a table, `NEW_TABLE`, from some of another table columns ,`OLD_TABLE`.

I added a new column  `ID` of type double

I want to fill the values of the ID column with unique values and then make it the the `NEW_TABLE` key.

Is there a way to do this in MySQL with a query or a set command?

I tried something like this:

```
Insert into NEW_TABLE
(select  generateId() , col1, col2 
 from ORIGINAL_TABLE)
```

Comment: Why `DOUBLE` and not `INT` or `BIGINT`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
Insert into NEW_TABLE
(select   @row := @row + 1 as generateId, col1, col2 
 from ORIGINAL_TABLE, (SELECT @row := 0)row)
```

Answer (score 2):

Usually you set the field to be an auto increment field when it is defined. To do so afterwards, you can use:

```
ALTER TABLE NEW_TABLE MODIFY ID int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment;
```

To then insert an new record and for it to automatically get an assigned ID, merely omit the field from the insert.

Answer (score 1):

You should use autoincrement and an integer field (is there any reason for you to want a double key there?):

```
CREATE TABLE NEW_TABLE (
     id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     col1 CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     col2 CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why did you choose `DOUBLE` and not an integer datatype?

```
ALTER TABLE NEW_TABLE
  MODIFY ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ;

ALTER TABLE NEW_TABLE
  ADD CONSTRAINT new_table_pk
    PRIMARY KEY (ID) ;
```

and then:

```
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE 
  (col1, col2)
SELECT col1, col2 
FROM ORIGINAL_TABLE ;
```